# Avoid Permgen Space error when running Tomcat from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat

What is the best way to avoid permgen space error when running Tomcat from Eclipse 3.6?
Is this done by adding the following line:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

at the end of `eclipse.ini`? Or is there extra configuration necessary?

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/OutOfMemory

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The configuration in `eclipse.ini` is **only** for the JVM that actually runs Eclipse.

Tomcat is run in its own JVM instance, so you'll need that separately.

Assuming you use WTP to start your Tomcat instance, you need to go to your Server configuration, click "Open launch configuration" and there (on the "Arguments" tab) edit/add the VM arguments to include the desired `-XX:MaxPermSize` argument.

Comment: adding the argument to the end of the variables, right: `-Dcatalina.base="C:\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0" -Dcatalina.home="D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.22" -Dwtp.deploy="C:\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.22\endorsed"
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

Answer (score 17):

No. Tomcat runs in a separate JVM from eclipse. Add this option in the VM arguments of the launch configuration :

- double-click on the Tomcat server in the Servers view
- click on the link "Open launch configuration"
- switch to the Arguments tab
- add -XX:MaxPermSize=512m in the VM arguments text area