# Eclipse:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

My eclipse configuration.

Eclipse : latest version **(Kepler)**

My eclipse **config.ini**

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20130521-0416
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40M
-Xmx512M
```

After Updation From to Juno to Kepler.But with the same `configuration` I did'nt face any issue.

Exception I'm facing is

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:381)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:377)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateMethod(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.BeanPopulator.invokeMethodAsPrivileged(BeanPopulator.java:221)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.BeanPopulator.doit(BeanPopulator.java:194)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.BeanPopulator.processSetterMethod(BeanPopulator.java:172)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.BeanPopulator.populate(BeanPopulator.java:270)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.replicator.ReplicatorTemplate.populateBean(ReplicatorTemplate.java:174)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.replicator.BeanReplicator.replicateBean(BeanReplicator.java:173)
    at net.sf.beanlib.hibernate3.Hibernate3JavaBeanReplicator.replicateBean(Hibernate3JavaBeanReplicator.java:71)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.replicator.ReplicatorTemplate.replicateByBeanReplicatable(ReplicatorTemplate.java:125)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.replicator.ReplicatorTemplate.replicate(ReplicatorTemplate.java:120)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.replicator.ReplicatorTemplate.replicate(ReplicatorTemplate.java:67)
    at net.sf.beanlib.hibernate3.Hibernate3CollectionReplicator.replicate(Hibernate3CollectionReplicator.java:143)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.replicator.CollectionReplicator.replicateCollection(CollectionReplicator.java:88)
    at net.sf.beanlib.hibernate3.Hibernate3CollectionReplicator.replicateCollection(Hibernate3CollectionReplicator.java:79)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.replicator.ReplicatorTemplate.replicate(ReplicatorTemplate.java:101)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.BeanTransformer.transform(BeanTransformer.java:224)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.BeanPopulator.doit(BeanPopulator.java:201)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.BeanPopulator.processSetterMethod(BeanPopulator.java:172)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.BeanPopulator.populate(BeanPopulator.java:270)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.replicator.ReplicatorTemplate.populateBean(ReplicatorTemplate.java:174)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.replicator.BeanReplicator.replicateBean(BeanReplicator.java:173)
    at net.sf.beanlib.hibernate3.Hibernate3JavaBeanReplicator.replicateBean(Hibernate3JavaBeanReplicator.java:71)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.replicator.ReplicatorTemplate.replicateByBeanReplicatable(ReplicatorTemplate.java:125)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.replicator.ReplicatorTemplate.replicate(ReplicatorTemplate.java:120)
      [ERROR] Out of memory; to increase the amount of memory, use the -Xmx flag at startup (java -Xmx128M ...)
```

It's keep telling me

> [ERROR] Out of memory; to increase the amount of memory, use the -Xmx flag at startup (java -Xmx128M ...)

Here is my VM args

[image]

What could be the issue..

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Whilst this dealt with Tomcat, not Eclipse, it might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @AndrewMartin Where does tomcat came in between?  I'm not using tomcat.

Comment: It's the same process. See here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_permgen_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Comment: **Look [here][1] for the ways to avoid PermGen.**


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878306/avoid-permgen-space-error-when-running-tomcat-from-eclipse

Comment: vmargs and -XX are both useful, but in different way. Look http://stackoverflow.com/a/10814631/715269

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#Why_am_I_getting_a_java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:_PermGen_space.3F)-

> **Why am I getting a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space?**
>
> The default maximum Permanent Generation space set by your JRE may be
>   too small. This is unrelated to the maximum allowed Heap space. You
>   can increase the maximum PermGen size by launching Eclipse with the VM
>   argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

Comment: Thanks man.I didn't set this in my Indigo and working fine.Don't know what's wrong with Kepler :). You made my day.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ You could have them in -vmargs in eclipse.ini file. Therefore, XX parameters were set as default ones. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10814631/715269

Comment: What about the EXPORTED app?

Answer (score 1):

Increase -vmargs to 512 & 1024 in eclipse.ini & close the eclipse & open it again.

Hopefully it will solve the issue.

Comment: This will increase the heap not the permgen space, you need to set -XX:MaxPermSize

Answer (score 0):

This problem might also be due to there being too many apps in the launch list when you `Run As ... Run on Server` in eclipse.

To find out of this is the cause of the problem, you can just click `Next` to see the list of apps that will be launched, instead of rushing through to click `Finish`.

If you see other apps besides the one you want to launch, just remove all the unwanted apps so that only your app is selected, and then click `Finish`.  This will require much less memory and thus not require you to jack up the PermGen space.